# PHP mobile detection with new iPadOS/iOS 13

Tags: php, ios, ipad, http-referer

I was wondering if there was any documentation or any new libraries which can detect the new iPadOS / iOS 13?

They used to output:

`mozilla/5.0 (ipad; cpu iphone os 12_1_3 like mac os x) applewebkit/605.1.15 (khtml, like gecko) version/12.0 mobile/15e148 safari/604.1`

But are now outputting:

`mozilla/5.0 (macintosh; intel mac os x 10_15) applewebkit/605.1.15 (khtml, like gecko) version/13.0.1 safari/605.1.15`

Has anyone come across this? Any new libraries to use?

Comment: turns out is the new addition to the mobile devices to prevent crops site tracking - which makes sense. don’t want to submit as answer as it’s not solving the question for new detection. https://www.apple.com/business/docs/site/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best I got as a solution was to use javascript:

```js
// iPad check
if( (window.screen.height / window.screen.width == 1024 / 768) || 
    (window.screen.height / window.screen.width == 1112 / 834) ||
    (window.screen.height / window.screen.width == 1366 / 1024)
) {
    // do stuff here
}
```

Not as perviously intended, but the best solution I have.

Answer (score 0):

couldn't figure out a php way of doing it, but with javascript this seems to be the most appropriate yet
First detect if device is a mobile one. In recent iOS for iPad, this check returns false, which is practically wrong, but that's due to a desktop user agent.
Second test if the device has touch properties and see if platform contains the 'MacIntel' string

```
let isMobile = /iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent); 
let isIOSMobile = navigator.platform === 'MacIntel' && navigator.maxTouchPoints > 1;                                          
if (!isMobile && isIOSMobile ) {   
    //Desktop mode on IPad detected      
    alert("For the best experience we recommend switching Safari view to mobile"); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a php solution and it works fine for me:

```
<?php
//Detect special conditions devices
$iPod    = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod");
$iPhone  = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
$iPad    = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPad");
$iPadOS  = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Macintosh");
$Android = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android");

//TODO
if( $iPod || $iPhone || $iPad || $iPadOS || $Android){
//your methods
}
```

Comment: does this work in iPadOS 13? I wasn’t getting any iPad matches for that

Comment: @markb did you noticed this line:  `$iPadOS  = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Macintosh");`?

Comment: yes, but then it would also match devices on macOS like Safari

Comment: True, but this is the only way so far, you can add media screen size to make it more secure